# how insert unique random values without repitation in vector in java?

Tags: java

i want to create vector of big length of unique random values.

```
 Random rand = new Random();

   Vector randomProjection = new Vector(100);
        for(int d=0; d<100; d++) {


            double val =Math.abs(rand.nextGaussian());
            double h= (double) ((double) Math.round(val*10)/10.0);


            randomProjection.set(d, h);
        }
```

but the `randomProjection` vector contain duplicate values when i think to use `set` insert random values in it then insert from `set` to `vector` but `set` contain only some values not all 100 values .

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if the vector contains the value in order to increase the counter. I also recommend to use add instead of set. The reason is that you don't need to tell the vector in which exact position you want the new value to be added. You can just add it with `add`

It would look like this:

```
    Random rand = new Random();

    Vector randomProjection = new Vector(100);
    int d=0;

    while(d<100) {
        double val =Math.abs(rand.nextGaussian());
        double h= (double) ((double) Math.round(val*10)/10.0);
        if (!randomProjection.contains(h)) {
            randomProjection.add(h);
            d++
        }
    }
```

The idea is that you add the new value (i.e. `randomProjection.add(h)`) only if the vector doesn't contain it. If that is the case, we also want to increase the counter (d) meaning that we added a value. If `!randomProjection.contains(h)` is false it means we didn't add the value (because the vector already contained it) and we need to keep the current value of our counter, so we don't increase d.

For example:
d = 5 (because we already added 5 elements, i.e. 1,5,20,6,3)
h = 4
randomProjection.contains(h) = true (because 4 was not in the vector), so we increase d and now d=6

In the same example if h = 6 instead
randomProjection.contains(h) = false (because the vector contains value 6 already), so d remains 5

In this way you make sure that you are adding 100 distinct values.

I would also advice you to use a Set instead of a Vector, the reason is that in this way you can just add 100 values using the counter and forget about checking for contains, which is a costly operation on a Vector. It would look like this:

```
Random rand = new Random();

Set randomProjection = new Set(100);
int d=0;

while(d<100) {
    double val =Math.abs(rand.nextGaussian());
    double h= (double) ((double) Math.round(val*10)/10.0);
    boolean added = randomProjection.add(h);
    if (added) {
        d++
    }
}
```

And one more note: Always remember to parameterize your Java structures, i.e. `Vector<Double> randomProjection = new Vector<>(100);`

Comment: i dont find contains or add methods in netbeans 8

Comment: I updated my answer because you don't need to use contains and, without using it, it is more efficient. But both methods exist in Java, see javadoc: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html#set(int,%20E)

Comment: ,still insert duplicate values  'int d=0;
 Vector randomProjection = new Vector(100);
                while(d<100)
                {
          double val =Math.abs(rand.nextGaussian());
                       
         double h= (double) ((double) Math.round(val*10)/10.0);
                        boolean added=  randomProjection.add(h);
                           if(added) {
                                   d++;
                                }
                        
  }'

Comment: Ah sorry, I thought it was a Set, so duplicates would be ignored. Now I saw it is a Vector. I will update my answer.